# Observable subscription unable to handle continuously incoming data with very short interval

Tags: javascript, angular, websocket, rxjs, observable

My Angular 4 front-end has a websocket connection using a observable subscription. When the observable is receiving data very fast within a short interval the front-end lags and completely blocks.

Is there a way to buffer the received data and execute the `next` event handler with a delay between every event? Or some other kind of solution that achieves the same effect. I essentially need to slow down handling of the `next` event but not miss out on any data.

I've looked at the [throttle](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/throttle.html) function but that skips data and I don't want that. Something similar that allows all data to pass but runs the event handler with a delay is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slowing down fast-moving streams is often referred to as "backpressure". There's a good (if a little out-of-date) article at https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/backpressure.md.

In your specific case you've said that you don't want lose any data, so you'll need to use a "loss-less" backpressure method such as `buffer` or `window`. From what you've said it sounds like `buffer` is what you're after. You can use `buffer` with a "closing selector" to determine when to close out a buffer and start a new one.